# Test class for the code below

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

// Hi Community, I need a help to write a test class for this code, can someone help me with?

```
    public with sharing class PropRentTotalSum {
        public static void RentTotal(List<Fee__c> fees) {

            List<Id> ids = new List<Id>();
            List<Property__c> properties = new List<Property__c>();
            for (Fee__c fee : fees) {
                ids.add(fee.Property__c);
            }
            for (Property__c p : [
                    SELECT Id,Monthly_Rate__c, (SELECT Id, Cost__c FROM Fees__r)
                    FROM Property__c
                    WHERE Id = :ids
            ]) {
                Decimal sum = 0;
                for (Fee__c fee : p.Fees__r) {
                    sum = sum + fee.Cost__c;
                }
                p.Monthly_Rate__c = sum;
                properties.add(p);
            }
            try {
                update properties ;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.debug('Exception :' + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should never swallow exceptions like that.

Comment: well done, big help was provided!